# Extend dynamic object with signature index in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

this might be a really simple question after all. But I didn't find a solution yet.

I have a dynamic object defined with a signature index. Usually, all properties should be of type string. But there are a few exception. `width` for example should always be of type `number`. Yet when I add it to my interface I get the error

```
error TS2411: Property 'width' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
```

This would be my interface:

```
interface DynamicStyleObject {
  [ key : string ] : string;
  width : number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sometimes your property can be a `number`, you can make the index type `string | number`, so it accepts either number or string properties.

```
interface DynamicStyleObject {
  [ key : string ] : string|number;
  width : number;
}
```

Ref.: [Discriminated unions, also known as tagged unions or algebraic data types pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: So it is not possible to have a default type of `string` and only for `width` having `number`?

Comment: Oh ok, I just found that I can "extend" it this way, saying that in general both `string` and `number` are allowed but for `width` only `number` is valid.

Comment: @lumio yes that's what I meant, sorry I forgot to add the width property (I've updated though). The point is, `string|number` will allow properties of type string and number, this way you can specify properties strict to one of those types like `width: number` and also `display: string`.

Comment: Yea I forgot the width myself in the beginning. No worries. Thanks for the simple answer