# Typescript problem when creating a recursive style object

Tags: typescript

I need to make a recursive style object, that can support style properties and in a nested format.

I have a super hard time wrapping my head around this, and I've tried pretty much all solutions I could find here on SO and google.

```
interface Properties {
  border?: string;
  width?: string;
}

//# 1 Type attempt
type TRecursiveProperties = Properties & {
  [index: string]: TRecursiveProperties;
};

//# 2 Interface attempt
interface IRecursiveProperties extends Properties {
  [index: string]: IRecursiveProperties;
}


const test: TRecursiveProperties = {
  border: '1px solid green',
  isActive: {
    border: '2px solid red',
    '&:hover': {
      border: '3px solid blue'
    }
  }
};
```

I'd expect the Recursive properties to be a fallback/catch all or some way to exclude keys from Properties object.

The 2 errors I get are either

> Type alias 'TRecursiveProperties' circularly references itself.
>
> Property 'width' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'IRecursiveProperties'

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend dynamic object with signature index in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453414/extend-dynamic-object-with-signature-index-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for this:

```
interface Properties {
  width?: string;
  border?: string;
  [selector: string]: string | Properties | undefined;
}

const myStyles: Properties = {
  'width': '100px',
  ' .child': {
    'width': '200px',
    'border': '1px color blue',
    '&:hover': {
      border: '1px solid aquamarine',
    },
  },
};
```

In this typescript resource: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures, search for 'Design Pattern: Nested index signature' to see a pretty similar example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I love the simplicity of this, I ended up going with this. 

Answer (score 2):

There is no concrete type that accurately represents what you're trying to do: namely to "special-case" some properties and exclude them from the index signature.  It has been [requested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), but so far there's no way to do it.

Notice that I said there's no *concrete* type.  You can represent it as a generic type to which you constrain a value.  So instead of having a value of type `RecursiveProperties`, you have one of type `T extends VerifyRecursiveProperties<T>`.  Like this:

```
type VerifyRecursiveProperties<T> = Properties & { [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof Properties>]:
  T[K] extends object ? VerifyRecursiveProperties<T[K]> : never }
```

And then you need a helper function to infer the particular `T` without having to write it out yourself:

```
const asRecursiveProperties = <T extends VerifyRecursiveProperties<T>>(t: T) => t;
```

This lets you do what you wanted:

```
const test = asRecursiveProperties({
  border: '1px solid green',
  isActive: {
    border: '2px solid red',
    '&:hover': {
      border: '3px solid blue'
    }
  }
}); // okay
```

and also gives errors if you violate the constraint:

```
asRecursiveProperties({
  border: 1 // error, number is not string
})

asRecursiveProperties({
  isActive: "" // error, string is not never
})

asRecursiveProperties({
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        border: 1, // error, number is not string
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

If that's too complicated, you might want to either loosen the constraint to allow the index signature to accept `string | undefined` (as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58805749/2887218)), or refactor your type so that you don't try to shove your `Properties` properties into the same object as your recursive properties, like this:

```
interface RefactoredRecursiveProperties extends Properties {
  nested?: { [k: string]: RefactoredRecursiveProperties }
}

const test2: RefactoredRecursiveProperties = {
  border: '1px solid green',
  nested: {
    isActive: {
      border: '2px solid red',
      nested: {
        '&:hover': {
          border: '3px solid blue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This refactoring might not be ideal for you, but it's much more straightforward for the compiler to reason about.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-2lZCbxBgHd70tXQ9WOdzX5lgBMBGRYN9t05fcf3PP8XGpU0m2RWV5XZHE8RAbkKCvSBaE7aNSXJAY8O7OFEOZNE5TZDld0wrtsN3Yj6z5AUhWgEVm1nesEOlZCqMVPRlRbGk1S7ET1QXQNSCAA)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide so much details. First solution is perfect, but I'm missing the autocompletion of the properties (border doesn't show up as I'm typing :/) Anything I can do to get that to show up again?

Comment: I ended up going with the simple version from previous answer, but have upvoted this as well. Thanks again for the help!